# Drawing on an Image

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

So I have a program that is basically like paint but made in Java and can only draw a few colours. By default the background of the program is white, but what I'd like to do is try to load an image and then be able to draw on top of that image. I can load the image but fro some reason it wont show the lines when I try drawing on it. Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PaintWindow frame = new PaintWindow();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class PaintWindow extends JFrame { 

public PaintWindow() {
    setTitle("JavShot Edit");
    setSize(668, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    panel = new JPanel();
    drawPad = new PadDraw();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 68));

    //Creates a new container
    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //sets the panel to the left, padDraw in the center
    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add the color buttons:
    makeColorButton(Color.BLUE);
    makeColorButton(Color.MAGENTA);
    makeColorButton(Color.RED);
    makeColorButton(Color.GREEN);
    makeColorButton(Color.BLACK);
    makeColorButton(Color.WHITE);

    //creates the clear button
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

    clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawPad.clear();
        }
    });

    panel.add(clearButton);
}

/*
 * makes a button that changes the color
 * @param color the color used for the button
 */
public void makeColorButton(final Color color) {
    JButton tempButton = new JButton();
    tempButton.setBackground(color);
    tempButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    panel.add(tempButton);
    tempButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawPad.changeColor(color);
        }
    });
}

private JPanel panel;
private PadDraw drawPad;
}

class PadDraw extends JComponent {

//this is gonna be your image that you draw on
Image image;
//this is what we'll be using to draw on
Graphics2D graphics2D;
//these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates
int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

public PadDraw() {
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        //if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
        //coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        //while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
        //then it draws a line at the coordinates
        //it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();

            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX + 1, oldY + 1, currentX + 1, currentY + 1);
            repaint();

            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }
    });
}

//this is the painting bit
//if it has nothing on it then
//it creates an image the size of the window
//sets the value of Graphics as the image
//sets the rendering
//runs the clear() method
//then it draws the image
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Untitled.png"));
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    if(image == null) {

        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        clear();
    } 

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

//this is the clear
//it sets the colors as white
//then it fills the window with white
//thin it sets the color back to black
public void clear() {
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}

public void changeColor(Color theColor) {
    graphics2D.setPaint(theColor);
    repaint();
}
}
```

I load the image here:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Untitled.png"));
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You have a couple of never events in your posted code: you should *never* load files or do anything time consuming within `paintComponent`. You should *never* ignore exceptions as you are doing. You should *never* call `repaint()` from within `paintComponent(...)`. Consider going through some tutorials first as it appears that you may be guessing at things that should not be guessed at.

Answer (score 4):

Painting is a destructive process.  That is, each time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint what ever it is you need to displayed the screen, entirely from scratch.

There are (at least) two immediate issues with your approach

1. You are not calling `super.paintComponent`, this will effect the way in which the paint process updates the screen, this VERY important as you have extended from `JComponent` which is transparent by default and may compromise the ability for the framework to function correctly (leaving nasty paint artifacts all over the place) - also remember, `Graphics` is a shared resource.  All the other components that are to be painted will share this resource, meaning that you could end up with what ever was painted before you being left on the screen.
2. You are re-loading your image EVERY time `paintComponent` is called.  This means, that what ever you painted to `graphics2D` is going to be lost.

I wouldn't bother `setDoubleBuffered(false)` as this will effect the way in which the component is updated and could produce undesirable results.

I would add each point you want to draw to a `List` of some kind and paint this list within the `paintComponent` method.

Don't load resources within any `paintXxx` method.  These should be prepared before hand.

I can see that you are "trying" to perform some kind of double buffering, but this isn't really how it should be done.  You are going little from it other then problems.  Start with a simple solution first.